# How to build web.xml based by java at spring speically error-page

Tags: java, xml, spring

i have small proble to built project without xml

i do this code from xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error_404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

to

```
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
    HandlerExceptionResolver errorHandler () {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver smer = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
        //exception to view name mapping
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(NullPointerException.class.getName(), "error_404");

        //mapping status code with view response.
        smer.addStatusCode("error_404", 404);
        //s.addStatusCode("/error_404.html", 404);

        //setting default error view
        smer.setDefaultErrorView("error_404");
        //setting default status code
        smer.setDefaultStatusCode(400);

        return smer;
    }
}
```

but as u know it's not working.

i hope to know someone show how to set error-page bean by java.

thanks for read it all :D

Comment: Those things aren't the same, and the `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` maps to a view. I doubt that `/error_404.html` is a view resolved by Spring but rather a static page somewhere in your application.

Comment: i understands i do all wrong but i can find other bean based by java but i can't find mapped error-page based by java... if it can possible can u give me some way or if not please let me know.

Comment: There is no `error-page` java replacement in the servlet spec. You either have to use the `web.xml` or a `web-fragment.xml`.

Comment: i see i should use web.xml or apache. thanks for u comment u r very helpful to me